# Windows: How to read a file of my choosing, rather than the requested one?

Tags: windows

I am on a Windows machine. There is a script that pulls a file from location \\sharecomputer\folder\file.jpg. I don't have write access to \\sharecomputer. I would like to tell Windows on this one specific machine: whenever \\sharecomputer\folder\file.jpg is requested, serve C:\folder\file.jpg instead as if it was \\sharecomputer\folder\file.jpg.

How do I do this? I looked into symlinks, but they don't seem to work in this scenario. If it can be done for the entire directory \\sharecomputer\folder\ instead of a specific file, that would also work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is just not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If the entire server can be redirected, then you can put an entry in your HOSTS file that looks like this: `127.0.0.1 sharecomputer`

Now, when you access anything at \sharecomputer, you'll actually be accessing \yourcomputer.

Next, share `C:\Folder` as `Folder`.

This will probably really screw things up because this will redirect ALL communications to the server back to your local machine. But, it's about as likely a solution to this request as any.

Comment: I was hoping for something more specific than this since the remote computer has other things on it that I want to be able to use as normal.